# does Mobile-Friendly Test API still working on 2024?

Tags: php, google-search-console, google-search-api

i was about to get datas from  Mobile-FriendlyTest with google search console api

```
$request = new Request('POST', 'https://searchconsole.googleapis.com/v1/urlTestingTools/mobileFriendlyTest:run?key='.$api_key, $headers, $body);
```

but i got this error :

> Client error: POST https://searchconsole.googleapis.com/v1/urlTestingTools/mobileFriendlyTest:run?key=xxxxx%60 resulted in a 404 Not Found` response: { "error": { "code": 404, "message": "Requested entity was not found.", "status": "NOT_FOUND" } }

does anyone ghave the same problem?
I did a search and found multiple articles said:

> Google officially drops Mobile Usability report, Mobile-Friendly Test tool and Mobile-Friendly Test API

Answer (score 0):

The **Mobile-Friendly Test API** is no longer available, according to this [tweet from Google](https://twitter.com/googlesearchc/status/1731702833060237642)

> Today we're sunsetting Search Console's Mobile Usability report, Mobile-Friendly Test tool and Mobile-Friendly Test API. We believe these tools helped website owners make the web a better place - thank you for working with us on this journey! Read more at